# Setting up UIContextualAction size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontextualaction

I would like to know if it's possible to set the `UIContextualAction` size (width and height).

I didn't find any member in `UIContextualAction` that allow me to do that so I wonder if there is a walk-around to do this?

```
action.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:CGSize(width: 35, height: 35  )).image { _ in
    UIImage(named:"Delete")?.draw(in: CGRect(x:  0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35))
}

action.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
return action
```

[image: result]

### Update

I found this post, the idea behind is to use custom button and use UIGesture

https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views

Comment: @matt in fact what made me think about it is : in my tableview i set spacing between rows using uiview with transparent color, when i swipe left the uicontextaction take the whole height of the row wish kind a ugly in this case

Comment: I misunderstood the q., sorry! If you use an image you can size it, I think

Comment: U can size the image but it will not solve the pb cz the bakground will took the hole height

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You might use this syntax to set width and height for `UIContextualAction`:

```
let contextAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { 
        (param: (Bool) -> Void) in param(true)
})  

contextAction.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(160, 90)).image { 
    _ in UIImage(named: "someObject")!.draw(in: CGRect(40, 10, 200, 100))
}

contextAction.backgroundColor = .green
```

Comment: thank you , I tried this code but the pb if you set a color background like red it will not work

Comment: I update the post with screen shot and the code I use, as you can see the red background tool the hole row height. or I wanted only on the white area.